# Unable to get click events on back button and menu options using android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar on android version 4.2.2

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-toolbar, back-button, android-appcompat

I have a layout for an on which I have added a toolbar using `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar`. Following is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.riyaz.activities.lessons.EvaluationActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/session_rec_page_title_bar_height"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
        android:theme="@style/RiyazThemeModernLight.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:gravity="end"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/RiyazThemeModernLight.PopupOverlay">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    ...........
```

For enabling the back button I am using the following code inside `onCreate()` method of my activity (extending `android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity`):

```
// Setting up the toolbar ..
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    }


    // setting the action on clicking on the back button ..
    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onBackPressed();
        }
    });
```

The problem I am facing is that this works perfectly fine for android version 5.1.1 (Nexus 5 device) but I cannot click on the back buttons (and the menu options as well) for a device which runs android 4.2.2 (Nexus 4 device). What amazes me is that for some activities where I have used the `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` earlier works perfectly on both the devices using the code mentioned above. Anyone has any idea where I might be going wrong?

PS: The layout for which the back button is not working for android version 4.2.2 has a few custom views. Can that be an issue?

Comment: can you able to see the back button in the toolbar? And do you face this issue in all devices or in some rare devices.

Comment: Yes I am able to see the back button on the toolbar. I faced this issue depending on the API level. But eventually I figured out the mistake. There was a scrollview in my layout which was laying over the toolbar and hence I couldn't click it. Thanks.

Comment: are u using scrollview inside coordinator layout ?

Comment: API level ? does it specific to 4.2.2 ? or applies to many API levels ?

Comment: @RaguSwaminathan : Yes I was using a HorizontalScrollView inside a –CoordinatorLayout but since I realised I did not have any use of it, I removed it. Also, this behaviour was specific to API level < 21. Even when having a scroll view, it was working fine in API level >= 21.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is still having problem with this problem, I found a solution in my case. I guess the error was from my side. I had a `FrameLayout` overlaying my toolbar. Just go to the view option in the Android Studio and just see if your layout are not overlaying.

Comment: "There was a scrollview in my layout which was laying over the toolbar and hence I couldn't click it. Thanks." @Swapnil. I put this here for reference